# htaccess rewriting rule checking variables amount

Tags: .htaccess, url, variables

I'm trying to change /a/b/c to /index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3

I've got the rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index2.php?main=$1&category=$2 [QSA]
```

But I can't figure out how to make this rule flexible for various amount of variables.

So 
/a should rewrite to /index.php?a=1

/a/b should rewrite to /index.php?a=1&b=2

/a/b/c should rewrite to /index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3

hlep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not make it so complicated, just do 3 rules. If u want to rewrite at only numeric way u should do this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA]
```

Or alphanumeric way, replace ([0-9]+) by ([\w]+)

Or just pass everything to one variable to your script and let your code do the dirty job.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\/]+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: ontananza, you don't need to escape /